# File Modification Detected message from Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I would like to know for what reason I get these messages multiple times per day while my SSRS solution is open?

> The project 'myProject' has been modified outside the environment.
>
> Press Reload to load the updated project from disk.
> Press Ignore to ignore the external changes. the changes will be used the next time you open the project.

Here's some more info:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel Microsoft
> .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel
>
> Installed Version: IDE Standard
>
> Microsoft Visual Basic 2010   01011-532-2002361-70813 Microsoft Visual
> Basic 2010
>
> Microsoft Visual C# 2010   01011-532-2002361-70813 Microsoft Visual C#
> 2010
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 3.0
> 01011-532-2002361-70813 Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications
> 3.0
>
> Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010   01011-532-2002361-70813
> Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010
>
> SQL Server Analysis Services    Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services
> Designer  Version 11.0.2100.60
>
> SQL Server Integration Services    Microsoft SQL Server Integration
> Services Designer Version 11.0.2100.60
>
> SQL Server Reporting Services    Microsoft SQL Server Reporting
> Services Designers  Version 11.0.2100.60
>
> Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Integrated) - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509)
> KB983509 This service pack is for Visual Studio 2010 Shell
> (Integrated) - ENU. If you later install a more recent service pack,
> this service pack will be uninstalled automatically. For more
> information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509.

This message worries me because it makes me think somebody else is modifying the solution, and we have had weird things happening with settings being changed on datasources.

Why are we getting this message?

Comment: Do you use source control?

Comment: Sounds like your right, I would be worried too if i got that message and I was the only one editing a file! Sounds like another person has MODIFIED the file and therefore your 'open' instance is OLD and thats why your being asked to reload it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well .. it means exactly what you think it means. That while the project is open, the project file has been opened and modified in some other process (for example, you could open it in Notepad and add a space.) So when you focus away and then re-focus on the Visual Studio window, it alerts to you the change and offers you a chance to reload the project from the disk to take in the new changes.

When you *usually* see this message it's because of source control. The scenario is:

1. You open the project.
2. While it's open, somebody else opens the project, adds or modifies the project in some way, and checks in their changes.
3. You go and "Get Latest Version" in TFS or Subversion through some other GUI. The project file you get overwrites your changes in disk.
4. Now Visual Studio has a conflict between the project file it's loaded and the one on disk. So it gives you this prompt.
5. If you "reload" you get the version you got from source control. Or you can ignore and save your changes.

Now you get into trouble, you check in your ignored load, and now that other person's changes get undone and relegated to the change history!

Project files are tricky business with source control, huh?